# Does injective imply each $x$ matches to a unique $y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Injective means one-to-one matching, as in each $y$ is matched by only one $x$. However, does this mean that each $x$ matches only to one $y$?

Comment: The more common colloquialism for the now-more-popular "injective function" used to be (some time ago) "one-to-one function," which says it all, I believe.  ... the good old days.

Answer (score 5):

In any function $x$ matches to only one $y$. That's literally the definition of a function

Comment: ok i didn't know that for matrix mapping the same constraint applied

Answer (score 2):

This property of each x mapping to only one y is officially called "well-definedness", and every function (even linear maps defined by matrices) ought to satisfy it before any math can be done with the function.  Every injective function is (implicitly) already well-defined.